# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw3.lib'

Tags: visual-studio

I am **trying** to use OpenGL. Yet, every time i use Visual Studio and press Local Windows debugger I get the error above (LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw3.lib').

My file structure is this

```
DOCUMENTS
 - Visual Studio 2019
   - Projects
     - OpenGlProject
       - sln and everything else (including glfw3.dll, and glew32.dll)
 - External Libs
   - GLFW
     - include
       - glfw3.h
     - lib-vc2019
       - glfw3.lib
   - GLEW
     - include
       - GL
         - all glew.h files
     - lib
       - Release
         - Win32
           -glew32.lib
```

I am including the .h files with

```
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLEW/include
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLFW/include
```

The lib files are included with

```
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs GLFW/lib-vc2019
$(SolutionDir)/../../../ExternalLibs/GLEW/lib/Release/Win32
```

The linker input files look like this

```
opengl32.lib
glew32.lib
glfw3.lib
```

I thought I was doing everything right, so what is the problem? I've looked everywhere and nothing useful has come up. Thanks for the help in advance, cheers!

Super User Link: https://superuser.com/questions/1483664/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-glfw3-lib

UPDATE: I updated Windows SDK and I still got the same error again, so I tried changing the directories to exact locations (C:\something\blah blah), and I got all of these errors:

```
1>main.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(init.obj)' in function '_terminate'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(window.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_free' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(free.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(init.obj)' in function '__glfwInputError'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strncmp' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(context.obj)' in function '__glfwRefreshContextAttribs'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_strncmp' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strncmp' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strncmp.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)' in function '__glfwCreateContextEGL'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strtoul' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strtox.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(input.obj)' in function '_parseMapping'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(monitor.obj)' in function '_refreshVideoModes'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_qsort' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(qsort.obj)' is imported by 'glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)' in function '_deviceCallback@8'
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy referenced in function _glfwWindowHintString
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__strncpy
1>glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsscanf referenced in function _sscanf
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strcspn referenced in function _glfwUpdateGamepadMappings
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__strspn referenced in function _glfwUpdateGamepadMappings
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__realloc referenced in function _glfwUpdateGamepadMappings
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__realloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__realloc
1>MSVCRT.lib(chandler4gs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __except_handler4_common referenced in function __except_handler4
1>C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\OpenGLCourseApp\Debug\OpenGLCourseApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

So I changed it back to the $(SolutionDir) which I'm told we need  because everyone's computer is different and the username wont be the same, but SolutionDir is relative so it will work. So now I get the original error.

Comment: lib-vc2019 is not a .lib file, it is a directory.  Tell the linker about it with Project > Properties > Linker > General, "Additional Library Directories" setting so it now can find glfw3.lib.  The other linker errors you see after it now being able to locate the library are caused by glfw3.lib being built with compile options that do not match your project.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation, "Runtime Library" setting.  /MT is not appropriate here, it is only suitable for small programs that don't use libraries.

Comment: @HansPassant I did put the lib-vc2019 file in the Project > Properties > Linker > General. The Runtime Library setting “I believe” is MDT I’ll hwve to check

Comment: @HansPassant It was the code generation! Thank you so much, you have no idea how happy this is making me!